# How to create pagination for users list using custom array?

Tags: php, pagination, list-authors

After searching I didn't found any solution, So I'm wondering how can I create pagination for users list like that?

I'm highly appreciated your help, Thanks.

```
<?php 

    global $wp_query;

    $topuser = array();

    $avatar_size = 100;

    $args = array(
        'role__in'     => array('contributor', 'author'),
        'hide_empty'     => '1'
     ); 
    $users = get_users( $args );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {    

        $query = get_posts( array('author' => $user->ID, 'cat' => '3', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'  => 'post' ));
        $counter = 0;

        $post_count = count_user_posts( $user->ID );

        if ( ! $post_count ) {
            continue;
        }

        // get each post of a user
        foreach ( $query as $post ){
            $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ));
            $counter += $views;
        }
        $topuser[] = array( 
        'id' => $user->ID,
        'views' => $counter
        );
        wp_reset_query();
    }

    // function to sort array based on views count
    function sortViews($a, $b) {
        return $b['views'] - $a['views'];
    }
    usort($topuser, 'sortViews'); // sort the array

    //$output = array_slice($topuser, 0, 10); // slice the array by limit 10

    $output = $topuser; // all users

    $rank=0;
    $rankpostcount=0;

    echo '<div id="top-artists-contributors">';

    foreach ($output as $user){

    $rank++;
    $rankpostcount++;

        $query = get_posts( array('author' => $user['id'], 'cat' => '3', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'  => 'post' ));
        $avatar = get_avatar($user['id'], $avatar_size);
        $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($user['id']);
        $profile = get_userdata($user['id']);

        // update the rank for each user
        update_user_meta( $user['id'], 'user_rank', $rank );

        if (count($query)) {

        echo '<div class="rankpostcount-'.$rankpostcount.' single-item-9">';

        echo '<div class="members-name-9"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">' . $profile->first_name .'</a><div class="author-rank-9" title="Artist Rank">'.$rank.'</div></div>';

        echo '</div>';         
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

> **Update 1**

This is what I have tried to do but i can't access to the second page!

```
<?php 

    global $wp_query;

    $topuser = array();

    $avatar_size = 100;

    $args = array(
        'role__in'     => array('contributor', 'author'),
        'hide_empty'     => '1'
     ); 
    $users = get_users( $args );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {    

        $query = get_posts( array('author' => $user->ID, 'cat' => '3', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'  => 'post' ));
        $counter = 0;

        $post_count = count_user_posts( $user->ID );

        if ( ! $post_count ) {
            continue;
        }

        // get each post of a user
        foreach ( $query as $post ){
            $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ));
            $counter += $views;
        }
        $topuser[] = array( 
        'id' => $user->ID,
        'views' => $counter
        );
        wp_reset_query();
    }

    // function to sort array based on views count
    function sortViews($a, $b) {
        return $b['views'] - $a['views'];
    }
    usort($topuser, 'sortViews'); // sort the array

    $page = ! empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $total = count( $topuser ); //total items in array    
    $limit = 20; //per page    
    $totalPages = ceil( $total/ $limit ); //calculate total pages
    $page = max($page, 1); //get 1 page when $_GET['page'] <= 0
    $page = min($page, $totalPages); //get last page when $_GET['page'] > $totalPages
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    if( $offset < 0 ) $offset = 0;

    $topuser = array_slice( $topuser, $offset, $limit );

    $rank=0;
    $rankpostcount=0;

    echo '<div id="top-artists-contributors">';

    foreach ($topuser as $user){

    $rank++;
    $rankpostcount++;

        $query = get_posts( array('author' => $user['id'], 'cat' => '3', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'  => 'post' ));
        $avatar = get_avatar($user['id'], $avatar_size);
        $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($user['id']);
        $profile = get_userdata($user['id']);

        // update the rank for each user
        update_user_meta( $user['id'], 'user_rank', $rank );

        if (count($query)) {

        echo '<div class="rankpostcount-'.$rankpostcount.' single-item-9">';

        echo '<div class="members-name-9"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">' . $profile->first_name .'</a><div class="author-rank-9" title="Artist Rank">'.$rank.'</div></div>';

        echo '</div>';         
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

$link = 'index.php?page=%d';
$pagerContainer = '<div style="width: 300px;">';   
if( $totalPages != 0 ) 
{
  if( $page == 1 ) 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= ''; 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= sprintf( '<a href="' . $link . '" style="color: #c00"> &#171; prev page</a>', $page - 1 ); 
  }
  $pagerContainer .= ' <span> page <strong>' . $page . '</strong> from ' . $totalPages . '</span>'; 
  if( $page == $totalPages ) 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= ''; 
  }
  else 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= sprintf( '<a href="' . $link . '" style="color: #c00"> next page &#187; </a>', $page + 1 ); 
  }           
}                   
$pagerContainer .= '</div>';

echo $pagerContainer;
?>
```

> **Update 2**

Trying to update users ranks meta with ajax

```
function update_users_ranks() {

    global $wp_query;

    $topuser = array();

$args = array(
    'role__in'     => array('contributor', 'author'),
    'hide_empty'     => '1'
 ); 
$users = get_users( $args );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {       
        $query = get_posts( array('author' => $user->ID, 'cat' => '3', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'  => 'post' ));
        $counter = 0;

    $post_count = count_user_posts( $user->ID );

        if ( ! $post_count ) {
            continue;
        }

        // get each post of a user
        foreach ( $query as $post ){
            $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ));
            $counter += $views;
        }
        $topuser[] = array( 
        'id' => $user->ID,
        'views' => $counter
        );
        wp_reset_query();
    }

    // function to sort array based on views count
    function sortViews($a, $b) {
        return $b['views'] - $a['views'];
    }
    usort($topuser, 'sortViews'); // sort the array 

    $output = $topuser;
    $rank=0;

    // Update ranks
    foreach ($output as $user){
       $rank++;
       update_user_meta( $user['id'], 'user_rank', $rank );
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_update_users_ranks' , 'update_users_ranks');
```

> **Update 3**

Here how I set and get and updating the post views.

```
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0";
        }
        if ($count > 1000) {
        return round ( $count / 1000 ,1 ).'K';
    }
    return $count.' ';

}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {

    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //retrieve the current IP address of the visitor
    $key = $user_ip . 'x' . $postID; //combine post ID & IP to form unique key
    $value = array($user_ip, $postID); // store post ID & IP as separate values (see note)
    $visited = get_transient($key); //get transient and store in variable

    //check to see if the Post ID/IP ($key) address is currently stored as a transient
    if ( current_user_can('administrator') || false === ( $visited ) ) {

        //store the unique key, Post ID & IP address for 12 hours if it does not exist
        set_transient( $key, $value, 60*60*1 );

        // now run post views function
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26453313/11103484)** may work as guide to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @QaisarFeroz, I tried it but I can't get the next page!

Comment: I updated my question, Kindly check, Thanks

Comment: Did you changed `index.php` with your current page link on line `$link = 'index.php?page=%d';`

Comment: Yes, I replaced with my template page  `top-artists-full-list.php` but not working, Or what should i add instead of `index.php`?

Comment: Don't use template file link , Try `$link = get_the_permalink().'?page=%d';`

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Can you share  the output of  `echo $pagerContainer;`. Or if the site is online share the link to page were this pagination is required.

Comment: Thanks so much for your support, here is my page [link](https://www.cgartzone.com/artists-rank/)

Comment: Change    `$page = ! empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;` and `$link = get_the_permalink().'?page=%d';` to  `$page = ! empty( $_GET['pg'] ) ? (int) $_GET['pg'] : 1;` and `$link = get_the_permalink().'?pg=%d';` I mean avoid using `page` in ` $_GET []` as it creates a conflict with pretty links used by WP.

Comment: OMG! Working :), Thanks so much, You make my day, Please add it as answer so i can accept it, Thank you again.

Comment: But there are small problem, the ranking changed in each page, so how can i keep ranking for each user, check link again please

Comment: Try replacing    `$rank=0;`   with ` $rank=$page * $limit;`

Comment: All numbers not calculating from number 1, started from 21, maybe should I change `$rank++;` as well ?

Comment: Let me check the code again.

Comment: Set `$rank=$offset;` and `$rankpostcount=$offset;`

Comment: Yes!!!!, Thanks, I hope i can give you million +1

Comment: Stay blessed! Always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

        global $wp_query;

        $topuser = array();

        $avatar_size = 100;

        $args = array(
            'role__in'     => array('contributor', 'author'),
            'hide_empty'     => '1'
         ); 
        $users = get_users( $args );

        foreach ( $users as $user ) {    

            $query = get_posts( array('author' => $user->ID, 'cat' => '3', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'  => 'post' ));
            $counter = 0;

            $post_count = count_user_posts( $user->ID );

            if ( ! $post_count ) {
                continue;
            }

            // get each post of a user
            foreach ( $query as $post ){
                $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ));
                $counter += $views;
            }
            $topuser[] = array( 
            'id' => $user->ID,
            'views' => $counter
            );
            wp_reset_query();
        }

        // function to sort array based on views count
        function sortViews($a, $b) {
            return $b['views'] - $a['views'];
        }
        usort($topuser, 'sortViews'); // sort the array





        $rank = 0;

        // Update rank of each user before pagination
        foreach ($topuser as $user){
           $rank++;
           update_user_meta( $user['id'], 'user_rank', $rank );
        }



        // Pagination 
        $page = ! empty( $_GET['pg'] ) ? (int) $_GET['pg'] : 1;
        $total = count( $topuser ); //total items in array    
        $limit = 20; //per page    
        $totalPages = ceil( $total/ $limit ); //calculate total pages
        $page = max($page, 1); //get 1 page when $_GET['pg'] <= 0
        $page = min($page, $totalPages); //get last page when $_GET['pg'] > $totalPages
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        if( $offset < 0 ) $offset = 0;



        // Get users from array for current page
        $topuser = array_slice( $topuser, $offset, $limit );

        //$rank=$offset;
        $rankpostcount=$offset;

        echo '<div id="top-artists-contributors">';

        foreach ($topuser as $user){

           //$rank++;
           $rankpostcount++;

            $query = get_posts( array('author' => $user['id'], 'cat' => '3', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'  => 'post' ));
            $avatar = get_avatar($user['id'], $avatar_size);
            $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($user['id']);
            $profile = get_userdata($user['id']);

            // get updated rank for each user
            $rank = get_user_meta( $user['id'], 'user_rank', true );

            if (count($query)) {

                echo '<div class="rankpostcount-'.$rankpostcount.' single-item-9">';

                echo '<div class="members-name-9"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">' . $profile->first_name .'</a><div class="author-rank-9" title="Artist Rank">'.$rank.'</div></div>';

                echo '</div>';         
            }
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }

    $link = get_the_permalink().'?pg=%d';
    $pagerContainer = '<div style="width: 300px;">';   
    if( $totalPages != 0 ) 
    {
      if( $page == 1 ) 
      { 
        $pagerContainer .= ''; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
        $pagerContainer .= sprintf( '<a href="' . $link . '" style="color: #c00"> &#171; prev page</a>', $page - 1 ); 
      }
      $pagerContainer .= ' <span> page <strong>' . $page . '</strong> from ' . $totalPages . '</span>'; 
      if( $page == $totalPages ) 
      { 
        $pagerContainer .= ''; 
      }
      else 
      { 
        $pagerContainer .= sprintf( '<a href="' . $link . '" style="color: #c00"> next page &#187; </a>', $page + 1 ); 
      }           
    }                   
    $pagerContainer .= '</div>';

    echo $pagerContainer;
    ?>
```

Comment: Hello brother @QaisarFeroz, I don't mean to bother you but i had another small issue with ranking, Now when i visit this page it should be calculate the rank for all users but not working! every time i need to load the other pages for updating the rank meta of each user :( , there are any way to update the rank meta for all users without loading the pages for updating? Thanks!

Comment: @AdhamMohamed. I have updated the answer. Now user's ranks are updated before pagination.

Comment: You are amazing +1, Thanks so much :)

Comment: Just a question, is there a way to update the rank meta with ajax without visiting this page to update the ranking for all users? I don't need take much time from you, just give me a hint and I will search about to save your time, Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes it is possible but i think better solution will be to create a function to update ranks e.g `update_users-ranks()`. And call it right after the code where you update  `post_views_count` for a post. Anyhow, for ajax usage [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)  may help.

Comment: Thanks again helped me a lot, Kindly check the updated question, is this the right way for updating users ranks with ajax? if yes! how can i call this function into single.php to update ranks immediately when users post views increment?

Comment: First let me know how do you update  `post_views_count`? Do you use a plugin or your own code in `single.php`?  If it is your own code then call your function just after the call to  `update_post_meta()` something like this :   

`update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_views_count' , ++$views );
update_users_ranks() ;`

Comment: Kindly check updated question, I added how the post views works, but when i call `update_users_ranks() ;` after update post views `update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);` I got a blank page like error when i visit any post?

Comment: Remove     `die();` from function `update_users_ranks()` and `add_action('wp_ajax_update_users_ranks' , 'update_users_ranks');`  because we are not using ajax.

Comment: Aha! I got it, now every time the post is visited it will updating the the users ranks automatically, right? and i don't need to use Ajax anymore!

Comment: @AdhamMohamed Yes, exactly.

Comment: Now i don't need to add any rank var inside the users list page, I'll try to call the updated ranks from that function e.g `$rank = update_users_ranks();` Thanks a million @QaisarFeroz

Comment: Stay blessed with peace of mind and soul!